# gigya redirectUrl not working in showLoginUI

Tags: gigya

I have tried and used the gigya showLoginUI javascript plugin in my html. The plugin renderd the social icons. I am trying to use the redirect feature of gigya. I have mentioned the redirectURL in my javascript. still the gigya does not redirect to the specified url. Please  find the belwo code sample

```
gigya.socialize.showLoginUI({
            height: 85
               ,width: 100,
            showTermsLink:false // remove 'Terms' link
            ,hideGigyaLink:true // remove 'Gigya' link
            ,buttonsStyle: 'standard' // Change the default buttons design to "Full Logos" design
            ,enabledProviders: 'facebook,twitter'
            ,showWhatsThis: false // Pop-up a hint describing the Login Plugin, when the user rolls over the Gigya link.
                   ,containerID: 'loginDiv' // The component will embed itself inside the loginDiv Div 

            ,sessionExpiration:0,
            redirectURL:'https:...',
            authCodeOnly:'true',
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the gigya documentation, if the redirectURL needs to work the showLoginUI js should have the param

```
authFlow:'redirect'
```

included in it. This param is missing in your javascript. Please refer the documenation at

[gigya documentation](http://developers.gigya.com/020_Client_API/010_Socialize/Socialize.showLoginUI)